# Parse Multiple Arrays and write all possible combinations

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA in Excel to write all of the possible combinations of the contents of three arrays to a column to create a wordlist.

Currently, I know how to loop through the arrays and get some output that I want but I can't figure out how to build the loop to give me all possible combinations of the baseWord(n) & numberCharSet(n) & specialCharSet(n).

How do I properly loop through the baseWord array to get all combinations of each baseWord with the contents of the specialCharSet and numberCharSet arrays?

Example:
Cloud1!
Cloud1@
Cloud1#
Cloud1$
Cloud2!
etc...

```
Private Sub createWordlist()

Dim baseWord(1 To 2) As String
baseWord(1) = "Cloud"
baseWord(2) = "cloud"

Dim numberCharSet(1 To 4) As String
numberCharSet(1) = "1"
numberCharSet(2) = "2"
numberCharSet(3) = "3"
numberCharSet(4) = "4"


Dim specialCharSet(1 To 4) As String
specialCharSet(1) = "!"
specialCharSet(2) = "@"
specialCharSet(3) = "#"
specialCharSet(4) = "$"

x = 1
y = 1
z = 4
w = 1

For Each Item In baseWord
    Range("A" & x).Value = baseWord(w) & numberCharSet(y) & specialCharSet(z)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    z = z - 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need three nested loops one for each array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ScottCraner mentioned in the comments, all you need to do is nest 3 loops:

```
For Each word In baseWord
    For Each num In numberCharSet
        For Each special In specialCharSet
            Debug.Print word & num & special
        Next
    Next
Next
```